# Connection timeouts in web3.js

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

When instantiating a Web3 instance, I can pass provider options, including the timeout, e.g.:

```
const w3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('...', {timeout: 10e3}));
```

But seems like it doesn't affect the `isListening` call, when I'm trying to connect to an unhealthy node and checking if it's listening:

```
await w3.eth.net.isListening();
```

is waiting for way more than the timeout I specify.

Why is it like that? How can I force the timeout there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to have a second promise that is tied to a timeout.

```js
await Promise.race([
    web3.eth.net.isListening(),
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            reject("Time out");
        }, 10e3);
    })
]);
```